Passing Geometry parameters in HQL queries in Intellij Console
I'm struggling getting IntelliJ to accept objects as parameters (i.e. geometry-objects) when testing out my JPQL queries (hibernate-spatial 6.4.4) in my Spring application via the JPA-Console.
In the Parameters dialog, I can pass an id when executing the query:

select p from Person p where p.id = :id

But when I'm trying to pass a Point (org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point) as:

select p from Person p where p.point = :point

I get:

[2024-05-28 10:04:15] org.hibernate.query.QueryArgumentException: Argument [new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(12.4545665447877771, 56.345345345663092));] of type [java.lang.String] did not match parameter type [org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point (n/a)]

In the IntelliJ Paramters dialog I've tried passing:

new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(12.4545665447877771, 56.345345345663092));

Same result when type-casting :

(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point) new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(12.4545665447877771, 56.345345345663092))

It seems that the JPA Console in IntelliJ keeps interpreting my inputs-params as Strings no matter what I do.
My JPA-configurations in my application.properties looks like:
spring.jpa.hibernate.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
